# Does the CBS documentary that is a plot element in Masters of Sex (season 2) exist in reality?

Tags: plot-explanation, realism, documentary, masters-of-sex

Episodes 10-12 (or thereabout) of [season two](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masters_of_Sex_(season_2)) of Masters of Sex  show the production of a CBS documentary in which Masters and Johnson are featured/interviewed.

However the [Wikipedia page on the real Masters and Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masters_and_Johnson) doesn't mention this CBS documentary at all. So, is it entirely a fictional documentary or does it have some basis in reality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible events they may be referencing in the show.  The first is from the show [ABC Stage 67](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Stage_67) which ran on the ABC network in the United States during the 1966-67 television season.  In a documentary episode entitled [Sex in the Sixties](http://www.tv.com/shows/abc-stage-67/sex-in-the-sixties-223564/) which aired January 12, 1967 Masters and Johnson did appear to discuss the changing sexual mores and manners of American society.

The other event the show may be referencing is from a Canadian television show called [Here Come the Seventies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_Come_the_Seventies) which ran on CTV from 1970-73.  For the March 18, 1971 episode entitled *Sex: Breaking Down the Barriers* [TV Archive Canada](http://www.tvarchive.ca/database/17228/here_come_the_seventies/episode_guide/) gives the following description:

> In the '70s the human biological function known as sex will be more researched, more exhibited, and will probably undergo more attitudinal changes than ever before. Featured are interviews with Masters and Johnson, Dr. Martin Shepard, a psychiatrist, a homosexual and a lesbian who explain the reasons for their preference.

Trivia about this episode from [Imdb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6666658/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv) claims

> During production for this segment, the Canadian crew traveled to St. Louis to meet and film Masters and Johnson in their own working environment. This may have been the only occasion on which a television crew from an independent production company was allowed to film in Masters' and Johnson's clinic. (Many years later, Virginia Johnson stated that no film crew had ever been granted privileges in their lab.)

Why *Masters of Sex* would say it was a CBS documentary though is likely due to Showtime and CBS both being under the Viacom umbrella at one point

Comment: Among these, I would guess the ABC one was the inspiration. But it's still 6-7 years later than the Master of Sex puts it (during Kennedy's 1960 election.)

Comment: On the other hand, Master of Sex (S2, ep. 11) also places a shooting scene at the Masters & Johnson clinic, and that seemingly happened only in the Canadian show. I guess they made some kind of mixture in the show for plot purposes.